# How do I dynamically link specific elements in Excel to Word?

Tags: excel, ms-word

I need to dynamically link specific elements in MS Excel to a Word document in a hierarchical fashion. MS Excel would be the data source, and it would ideally  update MS Word as per the example.

Initial thoughts: Use MS Word's dynamic linking (though it seems too basic for this purpose), use PowerBI (help here would be great), write a script to iterate through and spit out/update a word doc (though this would add significant maintence challenges for anyone without the script on their machine).

*E.g.*

Initial Excel spreadsheet:

```
+------+-------+
| ColA | ColB  |
+------+-------+
| A    | Text1 |
| B    | Text2 |
| C    | Text3 |
| C    | Text4 |
| B    | Text5 |
| C    | Text6 |
| A    | Text7 |
| B    | Text8 |
| ...  | ...   |
+------+-------+
```

To be maintained in a Word Doc like:

```
 1. A : Text1
    1. B : Text2
       1. C : Text3
       2. C : Text4
    2. B : Text5
       1. C : Text6
 2. A : Text7
    1. B : Text8
```

I appreciate any suggestion as to the best way to do this.

Comment: Which is the 'primary'? Are you trying to add things in Word, that exist in Excel, or add things in Excel that exist in Word?  Just to clarify - it sounds like you have a Word Document with various Headers/Titles, and you want to populate a Word document with those headers, yes?

Comment: Thank you for the question. The file exists in Excel, and Excel will be the source and should dynamically update Word, similar to the example. I've updated my post to address your concern.

Comment: By "Type" do you mean a Word Style type? It's a little unclear. If you update "C Text" in the Excel, is that going to be the same for *all* "C Text"?

Comment: I hope my edits (above) help to clarify. The Word doc needs to display, hierarchically, the information previously inputted into the spreadsheet. In this example, ColA is driving the hierarchy, whereas ColB is simply a text title.